# If employee 1 count = employee 2 count then print the one with the lowest count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named employees.  It contains ID, Date, Status, Employee_ID.
I want to get the one with the number of rows (count) and print the one with the lowest count.  If multiple employees get the same count, I want to print the one with the smallest count.  This is SQL Server.  An employee may have multiple rows in the table.  I want to count these rows.  I then want to see if it matches the count of any other employee.  If it does, I only want the smallest returned.

For instance the table contains columns id, and employee id.
The rows and values in the table are:
Row 1:  ID 1 - Employee ID 9
Row 2:  ID 1 - Employee ID 8
Row 3:  ID 2 - Employee ID 2
Row 4:  ID 3 - Employee ID 3

I want to to count employee id.  ID 1 and 3 would both = 17.  ID 1 is smaller than 3, so I want to print 3.

I have the count but am unsure how to do the if else

```
select employee_id, count(*)
from employees
Group By employee_ID
```

Any idea how to get the smallest count to print?

I tried this but it did not work:

```
select min(mycount)
from (select employee_ID, count(employee_ID) mycount
from Orders 
Group By employee_ID
```

Comment: In addition to tagging your database and providing sample data and desired results, please explain "If multiple employees get the same count, I want to print the one with the smallest count."

Comment: " If multiple employees get the same count, I want to print the one with the smallest count."  .??? . i don't understand  if the count is the same  .. what  mean "print the one with the smallest count." ????

Comment: I edited and hopefully explained it better with my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Employee_Id,
    MIN(COUNT(*)) [Count]
FROM
    Orders
GROUP BY
    Employee_Id
```

Comment: You can't do nested aggregates